# Unable to Uninstall yahoo messenger from system

Tags: windows, windows-7, yahoo, yahoo-messenger

Hi i've installed Yahoo messenger on my system.

Now i want to uninstall. But i can't able to uninstall through Control Panel\Programs and Features.

When i click uninstall button, a dialog alert displayed as

"An error occurred while trying to uninstall yahoo messenger. It may have already been uninstalled.
Would you like to remove Yahoo!messenger for the programs and features list?"

But unable uninstall.

My system os is windows server - service pack 1.

Pls help me, how to uninstall the yahoo messenger from my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another uninstalling software such as [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).

Btw, you could have a look at these links frome Lifehacker, they can help you:

- http://lifehacker.com/373120/completely-uninstall-programs-with-appcleaner
- http://lifehacker.com/276797/uninstall-programs-with-apptrap
- http://lifehacker.com/282337/completely-remove-programs-with-revo-uninstaller

Comment: thanks jmax. i installed revo uninstaller and successfulley force deleted.